# Yet another "can't connect to MySQL over the network" question - but i seriously tried everything

Tags: mysql

I was left with the easy task of installing moodle.

I am VPNing to 2 servers, one for the database and the other apache/php

server 1 must connect over LAN to the mySQL db on server 2

1. I added a user with following priveleges : 
   +---------------+------------+
   | host          | user       |
   +---------------+------------+
   | %             | mir        | 
   | 10.10.40.15   | mir        | 
   | x.x.x.x       | mir        |
   | localhost     | mir        |
2. Disabled firewall temporary
3. made sure that my username/password combinations are correct, flushed priveleges, restarted mysqld
4. i wnt to /etc/my.cnf .. if i try to add the port=3306 bind-address=10.10.40.15 or anything that is different from 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 - **mysql wouldn't restart**
5. i read and tried many forums and pages and asked friends for tips but nothing works

So my question to you :

- are there any networking extensions that need to be installed for mysql, how do i know nothing is missing from the installation
- any troubleshooting tips, any idea how to fix this, any step by step check list, am i missing something simple/stupid, please anything that comes to mind, let me know

Appreciate your feedback on this friday night stuck at work :P

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: i donno much about SELinux, should i disable it ? 
what command u recommend  ? 

i tried 

echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
then
[root@jimmy ~]# mysql -u mir -h 10.10.40.15 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.10.40.15' (111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was not from the mysql side, it was rather from the php/apache server 
all i had to do was "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

obviously there was a problem getting connections go out of the server that should request.

it made me waste more time than i should .. so i thought i would leave a comment to document a possible fix

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it listetning on any port?

> netstat -nap | grep -i mysql

2. If it is - is there any visible traffic from your client side?

> tcpdump -i [interface_name] -tnn host [client_ip] and port [mysql_port_number]

3. If there is traffic... are there any responses send back??

> tcpdump -i [interface_name] -tnn host
>   [client_ip]

Answer (score 0):

Pity you don't describe where exactly the connection broke or any error message. So here i try to put my general troubleshooting steps (apology if this is too n00b-minded):

1. make sure your web server can ping db server - if necessary - make sure the firewall allowing this (icmp and 3306 later on)
2. if 1 is ok, make sure web server can telnet to mysql's port in the db server.
3. if 2 is ok, make sure you can login using any other username/password (open any from any host, or use root username for quick test)

Which of those 3 you stuck with - and we'll go deeper...

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for feedback, currently when i

> mysql -u mir -h 10.10.40.15 -p
>   Enter password: 
>   ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.10.40.15' (111)

but when i

> mysql -u mir -p
>   Enter password: 
>   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 2
>   Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution

when i

> telnet> open 10.10.40.13 3306
>   Trying 10.10.40.13...
>   Connected to 10.10.40.13 (10.10.40.13).
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   4
>   5.0.77dAWsZLLz,Aq;m6cn$`=NOConnection closed by foreign host.

as for the netstat , here is output

> netstat -nap | grep -i mysql
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      16698/mysqld
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     264736 16698/mysqld        /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

for the tcp dump 
1403 packets captured
1404 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

i can ping the both addresses

any further ideas - really thanks for the feedback